# How to send mail from localhost in ruby on rails with smtp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, localhost, mailer

I am working on Ruby on Rails 4.0.1 framework and want to use active mailer to mail newly registered users on localhost:3000 using **smtp.gmail.com**, I had set up everything . Mail is processed in logs and it also shows "**Processed outbound exception**" but till now I haven't received any mail. Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in your **config/environments/*.rb** you can set up the action_mailer to look something like

```
config.action_mailer.deconfig.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'domain'
  :user_name            => 'username@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'xxxxxxx',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

**Note:** *If you are using the development environment, change the **config/environments/development.rb** to raise delivery errors, with:*

`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`